# JavaFX WebView overdraws itself and refuses to listen to any javascript function to make it auto-scroll to bottom

Tags: java, javafx

So I wish to use WebView to display rich text. Sadly I can not get scrolling to work :(

The snippet of code(xa, ya, xb, yb are the coords I need it to draw. txt is prebaked html text.):

```
    WebView render = new WebView();
    render.setLayoutX(xa);
    render.setLayoutY(ya);
    render.setPrefWidth(xb);
    render.setPrefHeight(yb);
    render.setMinSize(xb, yb);
    render.setMaxSize(xb, yb);
    WebEngine engine = render.getEngine();
    engine.loadContent(txt);
    engine.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
    com.sun.javafx.webkit.Accessor.getPageFor(engine).setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Comment: What does “overdraws itself” mean?

Comment: Basically, it draws over itself. In a manner of it not being cleared, thus making an absolute mess(making black bars in a way).

Comment: If you remove the last two lines (executeScript and getPageFor), does that still happen?

Comment: Nope, that fixed it, in fact making it the same colour as the background and not making it transparent yields the same effects without the mentioned problem. Thank you :)